# Insert Null Value or decimal

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

If we are working with `boolean` and SQL `bit`, you can specify like this to insert on SQL table..

```
oHotel.active ? 1 : 0
```

I have a similar case, but I have to check a decimal value where it will

```
decimal.MaxValue
```

When i have to insert a null if it is not maxValue i have to insert his value..

```
supplement.amount == decimal.MaxValue ? DBNull.Value : supplement.amount
```

but don't work, it tell me that can't convert a null value into a decimal..

Someone knows a short working way like this? The value can be `null` in sql table..

Comment: use decimal? and set it to null instead of DBNull.Value

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag as a SQL solution was not needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either the type of `first_expression` and `second_expression` must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other..[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

I don't think you can use `DBNULL` directly as your first expression .

```
      decimal? nullval = null;  
       or
      decimal? nullval = Convert.ToDecimal(DBNull.Value);
      supplement.amount == decimal.MaxValue ? nullval : supplement.amount
```

Answer (score 0):

use nullable decimals

```
decimal? oHotel = null;
```

Comment: Thanks. I havent think about use nullable decimals, but when i have the same check dont work, because i have the same problem, cant use dbnull.value with decimal to check his value..